# Set theory injective function&partition proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Suppose $f:A\rightarrow B$ is an injective function and $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a partition of $A$.
Prove that $\{f(A_i)\}_{i\in I}$ is a partition of $f(A)$.

This is a homework proof question and I have no idea. Could somebody write out the proof so I can understand? Thank you

Comment: If it's a homework question, you should offer some ideas first.

Comment: Can you include the definition of a partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\left\{ A_{i}\right\} _{i\in I}$ is a partition of set $A$ if

(1) $i\ne j$ implies that $A_{i}\cap A_{j}=\emptyset$

(2) $\cup_{i\in I}A_{i}=A$

(3) $A_{i}\ne\emptyset$ for each $i\in I$

So to be shown is that

(i) $i\ne j$ implies that $f\left(A_{i}\right)\cap f\left(A_{j}\right)=\emptyset$

(ii) $\cup_{i\in I}f\left(A_{i}\right)=f\left(A\right)$

(iii) $f\left(A_{i}\right)\ne\emptyset$ for each $i\in I$

Here (ii) and (iii) follow immediately from (2) and (3) combined with the fact that $f$ is a function. (i) is a consequence of (1) combined with the fact that $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

A partition of a set $X$ is a family of non empty disjoint subsets whose union is $X$.

Suppose we take a partition $(A_i)_i$ of $A$

Now take the respective "partition" $(f(A_i))_i$ let $f(A_i)=F_i$ (for ease of notation)

Assume $F_i\cap F_j\ne\emptyset\Rightarrow\exists x_1,x_2:x_1\ne x_2:f(x_1)=f(x_2)$

Which contradicts injectivity.

All $F_i$ are non empty as they are images of non empty sets.

And the union is the entire image, just by the definition of an image.

Thus this forms a partition.